# how to get running application/package name using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

in my application i want to write code of receiving broadcast for which application is running.like when we run/open any application my broadcast receiver should receive it.
how can i get the app name/ package name???

```
 public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH".equals(intent.getAction()))
     System.out.println("context..."+context.getPackageName());


}
 }
```

androidmanifest file-

```
  <receiver
        android:name="com.veg.app.Receiver"
        android:enabled="true"

        android:label="StartReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH" />      
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good way to do it using the activity manager. You basically get the runningTasks from the activity manager. It will always return the currently active task first. From there you can get the topActivity.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 // get the info from the currently running task
     List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

     Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
             + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

     ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
   componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

You will need the following permission on your manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
```

And there is **no such event** fired when any application is invoked. Any intent is not broadcasted on start of an application, so u might need a thread running parallely in background to monitor the top activity.

Comment: using broadcast receiver i should get any app is running..suppose i opened calculater then my broadcast revecei will get that calculater is running currently

Comment: u can create your own intent and fire it on change of top activity from your background thread but still u can go the simple way!!

Comment: U can put your logic in the thread tht will check the top activity and process it, If you want to invoke another activity on some condition thn u can do that from the thread directly

Comment: i can use this code.but doing this firstly i should know that new(any) app is opened.and by using your code i'l get the name of app

Comment: as it will be in a thread maintain the lastread top activity's UID in a temp variable and compare it with the newly read UID each time u loop into your thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28503/discussion-between-neji-and-yuva)

Answer (score 3):

you can use use [ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) to find the runnig application at current moment. 
It will return the [ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) of currently running application. Then you can get the name using [PckageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: BroadcastMessages are thrown when ceratin events occured. But at any time to get current running application you can not have any broadcast message